# Validar por cada fila recorrida una columna en especifico en datagridview c#

Tags: c#, datagrid, foreach

Tengo el sgte código que me permite recorrer el datagrid cuando el conteo de las filas sea igual a 2 , verifica si la columna del datagrid cumple con la condición y si es verdadero se asigna al sgte datagridviewcomboboxcolumn una lista, pero el problema reside que al parecer toma el ultimo valor al recorrer y este es asignado a todas las filas , con lo cual no cumpliría lo que requiero.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridPre.Rows)
        {

            if (row.Cells[6].Value.ToString() == "DENTADURA TEMPORAL")
            {
                DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboboxColumn1 = dataGridPre.Columns["Pieza"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
                comboboxColumn1.DataSource = dao.Dentadura.Get_Pieza_Temporal();
                comboboxColumn1.DisplayMember = "PIE_PIEZA";
                comboboxColumn1.ValueMember = "PIE_PIEZA";
            }
            else if (row.Cells[6].Value.ToString() == "DENTADURA ADULTA")
            {
                DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboboxColumn1 = dataGridPre.Columns["Pieza"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
                comboboxColumn1.DataSource = dao.Dentadura.Get_Pieza_Adulta();
                comboboxColumn1.DisplayMember = "PIE_PIEZA";
                comboboxColumn1.ValueMember = "PIE_PIEZA";
            }
        }
```

Si me podrían ayudar echando una mano para saber que estoy realizando de manera errónea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que deseas es que el combo box de cada fila cuente con diferentes valores dependiendo de condiciones, entonces tienes que usar DataGridViewComboBoxCell en lugar de DataGridViewComboBoxColumn :

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridPre.Rows)
    {

        if (row.Cells[6].Value.ToString() == "DENTADURA TEMPORAL")
        {
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell comboboxCell1 = row.Cells["Pieza"] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
            comboboxCell1.DataSource = dao.Dentadura.Get_Pieza_Temporal();
            comboboxCell1.DisplayMember = "PIE_PIEZA";
            comboboxCell1.ValueMember = "PIE_PIEZA";
        }
        else if (row.Cells[6].Value.ToString() == "DENTADURA ADULTA")
        {
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell comboboxCell1= row.Cells["Pieza"] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
            comboboxCell1.DataSource = dao.Dentadura.Get_Pieza_Adulta();
            comboboxCell1.DisplayMember = "PIE_PIEZA";
            comboboxCell1.ValueMember = "PIE_PIEZA";
        }
    }
```

Espero que te ayude.

Comment: Efectivamente es lo que buscaba , te agradezco por tu colaboración , al parecer me confundí y estaba evaluando por columna en vez de celda.

Answer (score 0):

Si entendi tu logica quieres que cada dos filas se haga la validacion que muestras,
manteniendo tu logica se me ocurre lo siguiente

```
Int contador=0; // para controlar el numero de filas par
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridPre.Rows)
    {
         contador++;
        if (row.Cells[6].Value.ToString() == "DENTADURA TEMPORAL")
        {
            if((contador % 2) == 0){ // compruebas si la fila es par 
            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboboxColumn1 = dataGridPre.Columns["Pieza"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
            comboboxColumn1.DataSource = dao.Dentadura.Get_Pieza_Temporal();
            comboboxColumn1.DisplayMember = "PIE_PIEZA";
            comboboxColumn1.ValueMember = "PIE_PIEZA";                  
            }
        }
        else if (row.Cells[6].Value.ToString() == "DENTADURA ADULTA")
        {
            if((contador % 2) == 0){// compruebas si la fila es par 
           DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboboxColumn1 = dataGridPre.Columns["Pieza"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
            comboboxColumn1.DataSource = dao.Dentadura.Get_Pieza_Adulta();
            comboboxColumn1.DisplayMember = "PIE_PIEZA";
            comboboxColumn1.ValueMember = "PIE_PIEZA";
            }
        }
    }
```

Agregar un contador al ciclo para comprobar si la fila es par , se haria cada 2 la validacion, espero sea de ayuda.